# "Recommend Deletion" button fails?

Tags: support

When I click the "Recommend Deletion" button, and only that button, in Chrome, I get the following:

[image]

and the buttons go grey

[image]

but I can still browse back to the page and the buttons re-enable:

[image]

But I still can't recommend deletion - only edit, ok, or skip.

Comment: I've only gotten that "Unable to load dialog" popup when my network connection is momentarily down. Next time it happens, maybe your browser's developer console has a more detailed error message.

Comment: It's been going on for as long as I can remember. I'll just have to wait for another low quality post and check.

Comment: Maybe "recommend" means "vote" (which you can't do yet) and not "flag" (which you can)?

Comment: That makes sense. I was under the impression that it was an automatic thing, and that button would flag it for further moderation. Maybe we could grey it out and/or make the text more specific?

Comment: I think I get the "normal" behaviour, i.e. I can recommend deletion and I get the normal pop-up, so it would not be what JoshPetrie is suggesting, but more what Anko is suggesting (the thing about checking the console log). I think if you were not allowed to do something, you would not get the option available.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, not a bug. Checking the console I found that the response was being blocked by our security proxy, possibly because it included the word "popup." Although it is a little strange that it allows the other popups used on the site, I know how to work around that.